# Suspend a certain method until CllocationManager finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a method (methodA) executed when application enters foreground using  `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` before calling these method i call  `CLLocationManager`'s `startUpdatingLocation` method, i want methodA to be executed only when `startUpdatingLocation` finish, i tried to do that:

```
- (void)applicationEnteredForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];

});
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    [self methodA];
});
}
```

the problem is that `methodA` still called before `startUpdatingLocation` finish, any idea about how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: You don't. That's not how the location manager and other async iOS frameworks are designed.

As Onik says, you should set an object (usually a view controller) up to be the location manager's delegate.

Search in Xcode help for `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Specifically you'll want the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method.

When you do that your `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method will be called when a location update is available. You'll then want to check the location update to make sure it isn't old, and make sure the accuracy value is acceptable. (The first reading you get from the location manager can be a very old cached location reading from the last time the GPS was active. After that, the first few updates can have really bad accuracy values. It can take 10 seconds or more for the GPS to settle down and start giving reasonable readings, and sometimes it never does (especially indoors.)

Answer (score 0):

when you call startUpdatingLocation, your locationManager start (and non stop) to receive new locations. If you want do something when you have the location, you should implement locationManagerDelegate, (sorry I don't have my computer, and I speak by memory) and the methods locationManager:didReceiveLocations, (or something like that).